# Est-ce que la phrase « Comment te sens-tu par rapport à la situation ? » est correcte?

Tags: choix-de-mot, constructions, formulation

Il n'est point question de comparaison dans le contexte, il s'agit plutôt du sentiment qu'une personne éprouve face à un événement, une situation exceptionnelle. J'avais en tête l'idée de recourir à la locution "vis-à-vis de", mais ne sachant pas si son emploi est correct  devant les compléments autres que ceux désignant des animés, j'ai alors opté pour la locution qui nous occupe, à savoir "par rapport à". Si ma mémoire ne me trompe, l'Académie française, dans une rubrique dire/ne pas dire, rapportait qu'on en faisait souvent une utilisation maladroite, sinon abusive, qu'on l'employait souvent mal à propos dans des contextes qui ne se prêtent pas à une comparaison, comme dans « J'ai appelé mon médecin par rapport à mon mal d'estomac ». À cet égard, les sages recommandent plutôt d'écrire « au sujet de ».
Merci

Answer (score 0, accepted):

« Vis-à-vis de »  signifie  « relativement à » (figuré, [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/vis-%C3%A0-vis)) et c'est une locution qui a un sens littéral : « face à face ». C'est une locution qui s'utilise aussi pour les choses et les concepts abstraits.  Donc, « vis-à-vis de » aurait pu être utilisé de façon entièrement synonyme.

Si on s'en rapporte au [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rapport) on trouve pour cette locution quatre sens (caractères gras et chevrons de user LPH).

> ♦ Par rapport à, loc. prép.
> < sens 1 > **[D'un point de vue spatial]** Savons-nous cette fois ce que c'est qu'un point défini ainsi par sa position relative par rapport à nous (H. Poincaré, Valeur sc.,1905, p. 80).
> < sens 2 > **Par comparaison avec, en proportion de**. Yvonne: De toute façon, cette petite est beaucoup trop jeune. (...) Georges: Elle a trois ans de plus que Michel. Hier tu la trouvais trop vieille... Yvonne: Elle est trop jeune... par rapport à moi (Cocteau, Parents,1938, iii, 2, p. 280).
> < sens 3 > **Pour ce qui regarde, relativement à**. Je traversais, par rapport à elle, une crise non pas de véritable amour, mais de vanité blessée et de sexualité morbide (Bourget, Disciple,1889, p. 184).
> < sens 4 > **À cause de**. L'année est dure, par rapport à la forte grêle qui est tombée dans le champ (Loti, Spahi,1881, p. 14).

**I**

Il n'y a pas de contestation en ce qui concerne la première définition (d'un point de vue spatial). On dit autrement exactement la même chose au moyen de la locution « *par référence à* » ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/r%C3%A9f%C3%A9rence)).

> ♦ Par référence à. **En se référant à, par rapport à... (pris comme norme)**.
>
> - La distance entre A et Z sur une droite ne se détermine pas par référence à A, plutôt que par référence à Z (Hamelin, Élém. princ. représ., 1907, p. 128).
> - La loi (...) leur accorde (...): − pendant la première année de scolarité: un traitement fixé par référence à l'indice 300 (Encyclop. éduc., 1960, p. 377).

Ceci montre qu'à ce premier sens correspond un sens figuré (à partir du second exemple : «
pendant la première année de scolarité : un traitement fixé par rapport à l'indice 300 ».

**II**

Le second sens, de même, n'est pas une source de contestation ; c'est le sens le plus courant.

**III**

Le troisième sens est celui sur lequel l'[Académie](http://academie-francaise.fr/dire-ne-pas-dire/recherche?titre=par+rapport&rubrique=&date=&form_build_id=form-0apyvzTbRVUSVkHvUh6B6SII70iP7UP60l2Z8du_zoo&form_id=academie_blog_search_form&op=Rechercher) à émis un avis entièrement négatif.

**À propos du** match, **en ce qui concerne** le match, il faut préciser que…
<s>Par rapport au match, il faut préciser que…</s>

Réagir **à** une déclaration
<s>Réagir par rapport à une déclaration.</s>

Je vous rappelle **au sujet de**, ou **relativement à**, mon dossier
<s>Je vous appelle par rapport à – ou rapport à – mon dossier</s>

**IV**

- Comment te sens-tu par rapport à la situation ?

Il est évident qu'il ne peut pas s'agir de « *par référence* à la situation » (sens figuré) : la situation ne peut pas être une norme selon laquelle déduire un état d'esprit  (se sentir). Il ne s'agit pas non plus de *comparaison* ni de *cause*.  On peut utiliser à la place de « par rapport » l'une des locutions suivantes.

- à propos, en ce qui concerne, au sujet de, relativement à, pour ce qui regarde

(« pour ce qui regarde » est  synonyme de « en ce qui concerne » ([réf.](https://www.synonymes.com/synonyme.php?mot=pour%20ce%20qui%20regarde)))

Donc, la phrase est correcte selon le TLFi (sens 3) mais pas selon l'Académie Française. Personnellement, non seulement j'approuve la décision de l'Académie, mais je pense que le sens « 4 » du TLFi est  aussi à proscrire.

Comment: — « Je traversais, **par rapport à elle**, une crise non pas de véritable amour, mais de vanité blessée et de **sexualité** morbide ».  Penser au non-dit et à l'écho tacite *rapport sexuel* … dans ce contexte-là, il est justifié.

Comment: @Personne Vous avez toujours le mot pour rire…

Comment: … d'un sourire gaulois (grivois du point de vue du convenu) tendance Rabelais, tendance qui a la vie dure et évolue avec son temps :-)